# PE header entry point RVA

Tags: x86, portable-executable, entry-point

I am having an issue with a non .net, x86 machine type, pe32 executable piece of malware I am analyzing on a virtual machine. The entry point field is not NULL so this rules out execution starting at 0x0.

When I break with a debugger at the entry point after creating the process in a suspended state, this program is managing to get calls out before the entry point. I am a little confused here, how exactly can this work?

Answer (score 2):

TLS (thread-local-storage) callbacks are called by the system before the application entry point. Here is a [blogpost](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=9) about that.